# cant change php.ini

Tags: php, ini

So I have installed Apache in `c:/apache` and php in `c:/php`
I have all tested php works `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
But I need two things to `change = short_open_tags` and to see errors.
I'm trying to change in `c:/php/php.ini`

```
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
```

to

```
; short_open_tag=1
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
```

After Im done with this I restart service...

`short_tags` dont work... What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`short_open_tag` is not there, do not edit that line, that is just the description.

Search for it down in that file.

it should be

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

or

```
short_open_tag = On
```